# Adding column dynamically at given position of table

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a dynamic table where I can add a column just by saying its column position and name.

for example,suppose-

```
name  age
aaa   23
bbb   24
```

is a table.If i say new column's name will be sex and column position will be 2, than it will produce the following table

```
name   sex    age
aaa    male   23
bbb    female 24
```

I am not sure even if possible or not.If it is possible,how?

My html code is

```
<thead>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="data in table">
          <div ng-if="checkIfCheckListIsToBeCreated($index)">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
          </div>
          <div ng-if="!checkIfCheckListIsToBeCreated($index)">{{data.columnName}}</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</thead>
```

JavaScript code is

```
    $scope.checkListColumnPosition=2;
    $scope.table=[
        {
          columnName:"Name",
          sign:0
        },
        {
          columnName:"Age",
          sign:0
        }
   ];
   $scope.checkIfCheckListIsToBeCreated=function(index){
       if($scope.checkListColumnPosition==index+1)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
    }
```

Here, i have used only head of table and if i specify a position for new column, new column is being added but one column from previous column's are not being shown.
[plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/HRWMLwork3yovyTAyv7a?p=preview)

Comment: Can you clearly elaborate on what is required on checking of the checkbox ?

Comment: New checkbox column is nothing but a normal column.like "name","sex","age","weight"....